# Display DIV for current month from months dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a **drop down of months** (January to December). When selecting a month, it would display a DIV for that month. By **default**, the **current month and the corresponding DIV would be displayed**.

So far, I am able to display the current month in the drop down by default, but I don't know why the corresponding DIV is not displayed.

Furthermore, when **January** is selected, the DIV displays, but then does not go away when another month is selected. This is only the case for the month of January.

**HTML**

```
<select name="month" id="month">
  <option value="0">January</option>
  <option value="1">February</option>
  <option value="2">March</option>
  <option value="3">April</option>
  <option value="4">May</option>
  <option value="5">June</option>
  <option value="6">July</option>
  <option value="7">August</option>
  <option value="8">September</option>
  <option value="9">October</option>
  <option value="10">November</option>
  <option value="11">December</option>
</select>

<div class="hide" id="0">Jan content</div>
<div class="hide" id="1">Feb content</div>
<div class="hide" id="2">Mar content</div>
<div class="hide" id="3">Apr content</div>
<div class="hide" id="4">May content</div>
<div class="hide" id="5">Jun content</div>
<div class="hide" id="6">Jul content</div>
<div class="hide" id="7">Aug content</div>
<div class="hide" id="8">Sept content</div>
<div class="hide" id="9">Oct content</div>
<div class="hide" id="10">Nov content</div>
<div class="hide" id="11">Dec content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
    display: none;   
}
```

**JavaScript + jQuery**

```
var CurrentDate=new Date();
$("#month").val(CurrentDate.getMonth());

document.getElementById('month').onchange = function() {
    var i = 1;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mp61hbno/

Thank you!

Comment: Just a comment, but HTML 4 and below do not support ID's that start with numbers. This may not work on older browsers. HTML 5 spec opens this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were really close. Have a look at the code below. I modified a few things.

Specifically `var i = 0;` and also the initial display.

```js
var CurrentDate=new Date();
$("#month").val(CurrentDate.getMonth());
document.getElementById(new Date().getMonth()).style.display = 'block';

document.getElementById('month').onchange = function() {
    var i = 0;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="month" id="month">
  <option value="0">January</option>
  <option value="1">February</option>
  <option value="2">March</option>
  <option value="3">April</option>
  <option value="4">May</option>
  <option value="5">June</option>
  <option value="6">July</option>
  <option value="7">August</option>
  <option value="8">September</option>
  <option value="9">October</option>
  <option value="10">November</option>
  <option value="11">December</option>
</select>

<div class="hide" id="0">Jan content</div>
<div class="hide" id="1">Feb content</div>
<div class="hide" id="2">Mar content</div>
<div class="hide" id="3">Apr content</div>
<div class="hide" id="4">May content</div>
<div class="hide" id="5">Jun content</div>
<div class="hide" id="6">Jul content</div>
<div class="hide" id="7">Aug content</div>
<div class="hide" id="8">Sept content</div>
<div class="hide" id="9">Oct content</div>
<div class="hide" id="10">Nov content</div>
<div class="hide" id="11">Dec content</div>
```

Comment: Great to hear. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You were not showing the content of current month, see this which might help you.

```js
var CurrentDate=new Date();
var curMonth = CurrentDate.getMonth();
document.getElementById(curMonth).style.display = 'block';
$("#month").val(CurrentDate.getMonth());


document.getElementById('month').onchange = function() {
    var i = 1;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="month" id="month">
  <option value="0">January</option>
  <option value="1">February</option>
  <option value="2">March</option>
  <option value="3">April</option>
  <option value="4">May</option>
  <option value="5">June</option>
  <option value="6">July</option>
  <option value="7">August</option>
  <option value="8">September</option>
  <option value="9">October</option>
  <option value="10">November</option>
  <option value="11">December</option>
</select>

<div class="hide" id="0">Jan content</div>
<div class="hide" id="1">Feb content</div>
<div class="hide" id="2">Mar content</div>
<div class="hide" id="3">Apr content</div>
<div class="hide" id="4">May content</div>
<div class="hide" id="5">Jun content</div>
<div class="hide" id="6">Jul content</div>
<div class="hide" id="7">Aug content</div>
<div class="hide" id="8">Sept content</div>
<div class="hide" id="9">Oct content</div>
<div class="hide" id="10">Nov content</div>
<div class="hide" id="11">Dec content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes to you js code, try this

```
var CurrentDate=new Date();
var curMnth = CurrentDate.getMonth();
$("#month").val(curMnth);
$("#"+curMnth).show();

document.getElementById('month').onchange = function() {
    var i = 0;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};
```

It will solve the issue.